# Will a high altitude gas cooktop work at a lower altitude than intended?

Tags: gas

Will a high altitude gas cooktop work at a lower altitude 1200 to 1400 feet?  Like a HPCT466GS/LP/H, which is recommended for use above 4000'.

Comment: Fundamentally, the question is what is the difference between the high-elevation and normal models. This is not made obvious in the spec sheet or install instructions. On the other hand, I don't recall buying a specifically high-elevation gas cooktop model, and I live over 4000'...

Answer (score 1):

High altitude models have smaller gas orifices to accommodate lower atmospheric air density (and therefore pressure*). It'll probably work, but you'll have less flame and heat for a given setting. It may sputter or fail to ignite at very low settings.

Chances are you can obtain and swap out just the orifices and convert your unit to a low altitude model. It is possible that there are other variations, such as with the regulator or supply lines.

Update: Here's a relevant [discussion](https://www.houzz.com/discussions/2314983/dacor-high-altitude-range) which asserts that these models are non-configurable and that performance may be reduced, as I suspected. Your only option may be to modify the orifice size by destructive means (not recommended as a DIY project).

<sub>* The [difference in pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure#/media/File:Atmospheric_Pressure_vs._Altitude.png) between 4000 feet and 1200 is about 20%, implying that you'd need about a 25% larger orifice at 1200 feet that you would at 4000.</sub>